# My CSS codes for background color for body cannot work

Tags: html, css

My `background-color` for my file**"styles.css"** does not seem to be working with my **html** codes. sometimes when I take away the `"body{ background-color: pink;"` in the **styles.css**, nothing seems to change for my **html** codes even if I put my other codes like `h1{color:blue;text-align: center;}`. When I tried in in **styles.css** using `<style>` everything in my **html** doc worked but the `background-color`. Please advise(I'm very noob).

These are my codes for html and css

My

**HTML** and **CSS** file

[image]

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA1VX.jpg]

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow, please provide the minimum amount of code to your question to recreate your issue please. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Your styles.css should not include the:

```
<!Doctype>, <html></html>, <head></head> and <body></body>
```

tags as this is HTML. Only the css code should be in this file.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code for your

```
<!DOCTYPE> 
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="path"/> <!-- this if your use external sheet-->

<style>
  body{
    background-color:pink;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**if you use internal styles**
always do it inside `<style></style>` tags or use `style` property inside the tags like this `<div style="background-color:pink"></div>`

**Or if you use external style sheet first check your path is correct.then add this to your .css file**

```
body{
  background-color:pink;
}
```

**if you code without any IDE, that meant if you code using notepad or notepad++ or something, always keep your files(.html,.css,.js) inside the same folder.then it is easy to link**